# Impossible to catch javascript exception?

Tags: javascript, promise, stytch

I'm calling into a 3rd party package that occasionally throws exceptions. The api is a promise (package is Stytch, calling CryptoWallets.authenticateStart, which returns a promise).

However, it throws an exception, and despite some documentation that says there is an implicit `try catch` in a promise that results in a rejection, the `.catch` is not executed, and it results in an unhandled exception which crashes the application.

I've reproduced this behavior with a simple promise. Note, I could put a try/catch inside the setTimeout function here, but the point is I don't have control over that part. Is there any way to catch an exception inside a promise? I've tried several things:

```
async function testException() {
   try {
     return await new Promise((res,rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('in timeout');
          // calling rej('') here works as expected, but not a throw
          throw 'thrown-error-here';
        }, 2000);
     }).catch((ee) => {
       // this is NOT called
       console.log('caught ee', ee)
     });
   } catch(err) {
    // this is not called
    console.log('caught err', err)
   }
}


testException().catch((e) => {
  console.log('caught at end.')
})
```

running this code results in:

```
in timeout
Uncaught thrown-error-here
```

I've tried with and without async/await, and tried awaiting at the top level and capturing at top level. Putting `try/catch` around the call to textException does nothing.

Is this impossible to fix without updating the package we are using? I believe the package is doing something similar to what we see in this example.

Comment: If the code inside the timer is the black box, then doesn't that mean that you already answered yourself?  The answer is:  Await that code as fast as you can, and either use .catch() or a try..catch.

Comment: "*Is this impossible to fix without updating the package we are using?*" Yes, it's impossible, since at no point is the promise going to be rejected. The exception in thrown outside the executor. "*I believe the package is doing something similar to what we see in this example.*" that's harder to actually prove. You have created *an* example of an exception that cannot be reacted on. That's not at all necessarily the same or even similar as what's actually happening. In fact, you seem to get an unhandled promise rejection in your application, which your example code does not produce.

Comment: @VLAS why do you say I get an "unhandled promise rejection" in my code but not the example? The output I show is from the example. I suspect you are correct, though, that I need to get the package updated one way or another.

Comment: Because in the code you've shown the promise is never rejected. Ergo, it's not an unhandled promise **rejection**. The promise itself just stays pending forever. Moreover, a pending promise will not crash an application and you say that whatever the library does leads to a crash. That's not the behaviour of an promise that never resolves.

Comment: @VLAZ i see. But, an unhandled exception does cause application to shut down (in node.js), so this code crashes a node app. I actually found the issue in an isolated code path that was missing `await`, so I was able to catch the error.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that I was right that your example was not reflective of the real issue.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes. And I thought you may have been right about Unhandled process rejection, but that wasn't the case. The rejection was handled, then a `throw` which wasn't handled.